# Can we overload malloc()?

Tags: c++, malloc, overloading, new-operator

i went through overloading *new* and *delete*, I was reading in a book that the difference between *new* and *malloc* is that new call the constructor,returns the type of calling variable and the third difference is that we can overload *new* on class by class basis, whereas *malloc* cant be, can someone explain this class by class basis also.

Comment: `we can overload new on class by class basis` -- all that means is that you can customize the constructor for each type.

Comment: ok, what about malloc??

Comment: can we do the same with malloc, i mean overloading malloc() as a function, becoz i dont understand why it was written in the book that we cant?

Comment: so is it like, we dont need to overload malloc so we dont do it, or there may be somekind of language error in doing it.

Comment: like if i want to allocate desired address or may be return address or size that is allocated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661148/how-can-i-store-a-value-at-a-specific-location-in-the-memory

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571086/allocating-specific-address-in-linux

Comment: @RobertHarvey No, user-provided `operator new` is different from a constructor and this isn't about hacking. The language provides facilities to call a user-provided function instead of the library's `operator new`, which usually calls through to `malloc`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`::operator new` in the global namespace can be replaced (overridden), not overloaded. This causes the override to be used instead of the function provided by the standard library. And `my_class::operator new` can be provided so it will be used in `new my_class` expressions, which is also different from overloading.

Overloading `new` only comes into play when you use the placement `new` syntax:

```
new ( memory_pool, 123, other_args ) my_class( constructor_args )
```

Providing extra arguments in parens after the `new` keyword causes another overload of `operator new` to be called, with the extra arguments appended after the `size_t` specifying how much memory is needed.

You can certainly overload `::malloc` just like any other function, by defining a version which takes different arguments:

```
void *malloc( std::size_t size, allocation_pool &pool );
```

This is just a new function that happens to be called `malloc`. But it's better to call library functions with an explicit `std::` qualification, and adding a `std::malloc` overload would be against the library's rules.

You can't replace `std::malloc`. The only functions that can be replaced are the standard variants of `::operator new`. There is no such thing as a class-specific `malloc` because it doesn't take an argument indicating the what class will go into the returned memory block. `malloc` has no idea what you will be doing with the returned memory; it's just a blob of bytes.

As a matter of program organization, a more specialized allocator should probably be given and called as another name, not `malloc`. If you have a need to call different functions depending on the type, use a template, e.g.

```
template< typename allocated >
void *my_allocate( std::size_t sz ); // maybe "sz" param is unnecessary.
```

You might also specialize `std::allocator< my_class >` and its member function `allocate`. Then various standard library facilities will call your function despite no customization of `new`. (You might avoid getting too deep into custom `new` because of its quirks.)

Answer (score 2):

Overloading `new` has nothing to do with `constructors`.  A `class` can provide its own operator `new()`, which is responsible for allocating memory prior to the constructor call.  This is useful for optimizing pools of small objects, e.g.  You might also look into the various overloads of operator `new()`, including so-called "placement new", allowing arbitrary arguments to be supplied for things like in-place construction (user-supplied buffer), file/line diagnostics, etc.

Comment: ok so i guess the answer is that for the case of *new* since overloading may be usefull in cases where we know the size to be allocated etc as it will be creating the object also. But in *malloc* we cant have similar kind of advantage as *malloc* is restricted to only allocating memory, so we dont need to overload *malloc*, there is no need and benefit of doing so.

Comment: @Praveen - that's correct, malloc is "type-less", returning just a void *, so there's really no basis on which to overload.

Answer (score 2):

NB: You can **not** "overload" or "overwrite" standard C library functions at your will, but it's common practice to allow you **to override a reasonable subset** of it.

In general, linker doesn't know about what language object file given was written on, it works on significantly lower level of knowledge -- with external symbols of object files, which **ought to be unique amongst all object files and shared libraries** being linked together because linker itself can not drop objects given on its command line with duplicate symbols at its will.
Notable exception is static libraries (.a) -- it's permitted to linker to drop any item or items from the archive if it helps to remove duplicate external symbols.

Allowance to override library functions consists of two parts:

1. compiler who has a syntax to mark a function as overloadable -- appropriate external symbol will be marked as "weak linkage". F.e., for `gcc`:

   ```
   `__attribute__((weak)) void *malloc(size_t size)`
   ```
2. dynamic linker(`ld.so`) which understands weak linkage.

It is unknown if `malloc()` is declared as a weak symbol in the particular shared `libc`, but generally it is, so, there're high chances that you would be able to override it, but **your mileage may vary.**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can overload standard library function malloc. 
Please look at the code snippet below:

```
    #include <iostream>
    void malloc(void)
    {
        puts("malloc");
    }

    int main()
    {
        int *p= (int*)malloc(8);
        malloc();
        free(p);
        return 0;
    }
```

This code prints *malloc*.

Also, following is the snippet of TEXT section of the memory for this program:

```
    0000000000400744 T _Z6mallocv
    0000000000400770 T main
```

and following is the snippet from DYNAMIC SYMBOL TABLE

```
    0000000000000000      DF *UND*  00000000000001d2  GLIBC_2.2.5 malloc
    0000000000000000      DF *UND*  00000000000001a5  GLIBC_2.2.5 __libc_start_main
```

Hence, we can overload the standard library functions like malloc in c++.