# Profiling stable_sort

Tags: c++, sorting, memory, in-place

This [page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/stable_sort/) tells that whenever there is not enough memory, `stable_sort` reduces to an in-place algorithm with running time O(n(log n)(log n)):

> ### *<sub>**Complexity**</sub>*
>
> *If enough extra memory is available, linearithmic in the distance between first and last: Performs up to N*log<sub>2</sub>(N) element comparisons (where N is this distance), and up to that many element moves.
>   Otherwise, polyloglinear in that distance: Performs up to N*log<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>(N) element comparisons, and up to that many element swaps.*

I want to profile it against another in-place algorithm with the same running time, so my question reduces to: how can I simulate a "lack of memory" so that the slower algorithm is performed in `stable_sort`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we overload malloc()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16270891/can-we-overload-malloc). Also have a look at: [How does sbrk() work in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076532/how-does-sbrk-work-in-c)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

cplusplus.com is notoriously bad... looking at cppreference.com's description [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/get_temporary_buffer)

> This function attempts to allocate a temporary buffer equal in size to the sequence to be sorted, typically by calling std::get_temporary_buffer. If the allocation fails, the less efficient algorithm is chosen.

[`get_temporary_buffer`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/get_temporary_buffer) is:

```
template< class T >
std::pair< T*, std::ptrdiff_t > get_temporary_buffer( std::ptrdiff_t count )
```

So, while it will technically be underfined behaviour to specialise it for your own class in the `std` namespace, you're presumably not doing this for production code and in practice it's extremely likely to work reliably and would let you intercept the memory request and return failure.

```
namespace std
{
    template <>
    std::pair<My_Class*, std::ptrdiff_t>
    get_temporary_buffer(std::ptrdiff_t)
    { return {0, 0}; }
}
```

Comment: Have a upvote  for saying _"cplusplus.com is notoriously bad"_. I'm out of votes today.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ oh wow - I didn't even know it was possible to run out of upvotes; you must be more generous than me!  Cheers.

Comment: You're running out of votes simply. It doesn't matter if you up- or downvote. I've given downvotes mostly today. Had one left now. It recovers with deleted questions or so. I don't know the exact mechanism.